# How to get 2 separate number averages from a text file?

Tags: java, text-files, inputstream

I am new to the java language and I can't figure out how to read one line at a time from a text file and get the average for that line.

My working code so far gets the average for the whole file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.io.*; 

public class NumAverage { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

        File myFile = new File("Num.txt"); 
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile); 

        int numbersCounter = 0;  
        int sum = 0; 

        while (inputFile.hasNext()) { 
            int numList = inputFile.nextInt(); 

            sum = sum + numList; 
            numbersCounter++; 
        } 

        System.out.println("Average: " + (sum/numbersCounter)); 

        inputFile.close(); 
    } 
}
```

This what the text file looks like

```
 1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn Java's streams API (knowing decorator pattern simplifies understanding it).

For your case, we can do:

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("nums.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
String line;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
    int tokens = tokenizer.countTokens();
    float average = 0;

    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
        int value = Integer.valueOf(token);
        average += value;
    }

    System.out.println(average / tokens);
}
```

In the first line I'm creating a `FileInputStream` that allows us to read from the file.

In the second line I am decorating `stream` as `InputStreamReader` and then as `BufferedReader` (the second one has great API for reading input line by line).

Then I am iterating over your file line by line (using `readLine()` method in loop) and using `StringTokenizer` I am splitting the line into tokens.

In the second loop I'm doing all necessary calculations.

Of course you need to remember about exceptions (I've ommited them for example simplicity).

One more thing that is worth to mention - you need to be aware that [countTokens()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#countTokens()) method should be used before consuming tokens - otherwise it will return improper value (it returns a number of how many you can call `nextToken()` before receiving exception).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Files.lines()` to create a Stream of lines of text, then parse each line into an array of numbers and average them.

```
    Files.lines(Paths.get("nums.txt"))
            .map(str -> str.split(" "))   
            .mapToDouble(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).average().orElse(0.0))
            .forEach(avg -> System.out.println("Average: " + avg));
```

`Files.lines()` takes care of all of the file I/O and creates a `Stream<String>` which allows each line to be lazily processed as it is read from the file. This is really useful if someday you need to deal with very large files that don't fit in memory, since each line is read only after the previous line has been fully processed by the Stream. It will automatically close the file for you when it is finished.

The next line takes each line in the file and converts it into an array of Strings, one for each number.  At that point, the Stream is changed from a `Stream<String>` to a `Stream<String[]>`

The next line converts each String[] into a number which is the average of the numbers on the line.  It does it by taking the array of Strings and creating a Stream out of it with `Arrays.stream()`, changing each String into an integer using `Integer.valueOf()`, and then calling `average()` to take the entire stream of integers and calculate the average. At this point the Stream is now a `DoubleStream`.

The next line takes each average and prints it.

The entire sequence of operations happens on each line, so the average of the first line is printed before the next line is read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need two loops. One to iterate through each line of the file and one to iterate through the numbers in the file. Modified you code to use two Scanners:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestAverageFromFileLines {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File myFile = new File("Num.txt");
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile)) {
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();

                int numbersCounter = 0;
                int sum = 0;

                try (Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line)) {
                    while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                        int numList = lineScanner.nextInt();
                        sum = sum + numList;
                        numbersCounter++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Average: " + ((double)sum / numbersCounter));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Also, division of integers in Java by default truncates the fractional part. Therefore, to force Java to perform a non truncating division you need to cast either of the operands to float or double.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
File myFile = new File("Num.txt"); 
try (Scanner c = new Scanner(myFile)) {
    while (c.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println("Average: " +
            Stream.of(c.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
                .mapToInt(x -> Integer.parseInt(x))
                .average().getAsDouble());
    }
}
```

result:

```
Average: 2.5
Average: 6.5
```

Comment: You have my credit for functional programming. But for Java-new-commer it might be an overkill. :)

Comment: Agreed, I'm a fan of Java Streams too, but in this case I think concepts like how to process each line of the file separately and how division works in Java are the ones a newcomer is mostly looking for.

Comment: Old programmers learn APIs in historical order.  But newcommers need not do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to also check for "\n"(new line),
and print the average inside the loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.io.*; 

public class NumAverage{ 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

File myFile = new File("Num.txt"); 
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile); 

int numbersCounter = 0;  
int sum = 0; 

while (inputFile.hasNext()) 
{ 
    if(inputFile.hasNextInt(){
        int numList = inputFile.nextInt(); 
        sum = sum + numList; 
        numbersCounter++;
    }
    if(inputFile.next().Equals("\n"){
        System.out.println("Average: " + (sum/numbersCounter));
        sum = 0;
        numbersCounter=0;
    }

} 



inputFile.close();
```

} 
}

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner object has a function `scanner.nextLine()` It will return a string which you can process as a series of numbers, because you know the format of the file.

```
 String[] myNumbersArray = myNumbers.split(" ");
 for (String s : myNumbersArray) {
      int myNumber = Integer.parseInt(s);
 }
```